# Running TensorFlow script after new image with dogwatch

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, raspberry-pi, google-coral

I have a Raspberry Pi 4 with the Coral Accelerator.

Here's what I'm trying to do:

1. I have a directory on the Pi where I can automatically upload photos from my phone
2. I have watchdog working that detects when a new photo is added (uploaded)
3. [My problem area I need some help or guidance]: In the `elif` for the new file created (image uploaded) I want to run the python script and commands to run the image processing to detect what's in the picture (coral accelerator)

The trouble area is surrounded by a row of asterisks.

```
import time
from watchdog.observers import Observer
from watchdog.events import FileSystemEventHandler

class Watcher:
    DIRECTORY_TO_WATCH = "/path/to/img/directory"

    def __init__(self):
        self.observer = Observer()

    def run(self):
        event_handler = Handler()
        self.observer.schedule(event_handler, self.DIRECTORY_TO_WATCH, recursive=True)
        self.observer.start()
        try:
            while True:
                time.sleep(5)
        except:
            self.observer.stop()
            print("Error")

        self.observer.join()


class Handler(FileSystemEventHandler):

    @staticmethod
    def on_any_event(event):
        if event.is_directory:
            return None

        elif event.event_type == 'created':
            # Take any action here when a file is first created.
            print (event.src_path)
            ******************************
            ******************************
            python3 classify_image.py \
            --model models/mobilenet_v2_1.0_224_inat_bird_quant_edgetpu.tflite \
            --labels models/inat_bird_labels.txt \
            --input event.src_path
            ******************************
            ******************************

        # elif event.event_type == 'modified':
            # Taken any action here when a file is modified.
            # print("Received modified event - %s." % event.src_path)

        elif event.event_type == 'deleted':
            # Taken any action here when a file is deleted.
            print("Received deleted event - %s." % event.src_path)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    w = Watcher()
    w.run()
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To extends on the previous answer, that is perfectly fine and will works, but not very efficient. The issue is that the interpreter/model/engine/labels needs to get initialized every single time there is a new file. This takes a very long time (almost seconds), where as each inference calls should only take ~5ms on the pi4 + the coral's accelerator.

Since `edgetpu's API` comes with modules you can call directly within your python script, here is how I would handle this:

```
# Add these imports
from edgetpu.classification.engine import ClassificationEngine
from edgetpu.utils import dataset_utils
from PIL import Image

# [EDIT] since user had issue calling "self" in the class, I'm making this a global variable so that it could be called anywhere.

print('Initializing engine and labels')
engine = ClassificationEngine('models/mobilenet_v2_1.0_224_inat_bird_quant_edgetpu.tflite')
labels = dataset_utils.read_label_file('models/inat_bird_labels.txt')

# Keep class Watcher the same
class Watcher:
.....

class Handler(FileSystemEventHandler):
    @staticmethod
    def on_any_event(event):
        if event.is_directory:
            return None

        elif event.event_type == 'created':
            # Take any action here when a file is first created.
            print(event.src_path)
            img = Image.open(event.src_path)
            for result in engine.classify_with_image(img, top_k=3):
              print('---------------------------')
              print(labels[result[0]])
              print('Score : ', result[1])

        # elif event.event_type == 'modified':
            # Taken any action here when a file is modified.
            # print("Received modified event - %s." % event.src_path)

        elif event.event_type == 'deleted':
            # Taken any action here when a file is deleted.
            print("Received deleted event - %s." % event.src_path)
```

Comment: This is a great idea! I'm getting this error though, any thoughts?

`File "watcher.py", line 47, in on_any_event
    for result in engine.classify_with_image(img, top_k=3):
NameError: name 'engine' is not defined`

Comment: if I prepend `self.` I get this message:

`File "watcher.py", line 47, in on_any_event
    for result in self.engine.classify_with_image(img, top_k=3):
NameError: name 'self' is not defined`

Comment: Weird, isn't `on_any_event` a method of the class Handler? Because then you can totally call `self`. The easiest fix is just to make `engine` and `labels` a global variable and you can call that anywhere. See edited code

Comment: Not sure if you'd be able to help me, but now I'm having a read problem with temp image files. I posted a new question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62801303/watchdog-ignore-pattern

Comment: the question has been answered!

Answer (score 0):

You can execute a python script using `subprocess.run()`.

```
import subprocess

args = [
    'python3',
    'classify_image.py',
    '--model models/mobilenet_v2_1.0_224_inat_bird_quant_edgetpu.tflite',
    '--labels models/inat_bird_labels.txt',
    '--input {}'.format(event.src_path)
]
sp = subprocess.run(args, capture_output=True) # Blocked until script execution is complete
print(sp.stdout)
```

Comment: Thanks, seems that this is bringing be closer to my goal. The `print(sp.stdout)` just outputs `b''`. 

Not sure If I'm doing something wrong. I added your code blocl in the `elif` for the created event (under it).

Comment: This is what I get if I print only `sp`:

```
CompletedProcess(args=['python3', 'classify_image.py', '--model models/mobilenet_v2_1.0_224_inat_bird_quant_edgetpu.tflite', '--labels models/inat_bird_labels.txt', '--input /home/pi/PiServer/Media/plant-classification/123.JPG'], returncode=2, stdout=b'', stderr=b'usage: classify_image.py [-h] -m MODEL -i INPUT [-l LABELS] [-k TOP_K]\n                         [-t THRESHOLD] [-c COUNT]\nclassify_image.py: error: the following arguments are required: -m/--model, -i/--input\n')
```

Comment: It seems that the option argument was not passed properly. Add "import sys\n print(sys.argv)" to classify_image.py to see what arguments it received.

Comment: Figured it out. I just had to make sure there were any spaces for the array of arguments, which meant just splitting things off more. 

Thank you so much!!!

Comment: The subprocess route could works, but generally that isn't ideal since all you get is text outputs. I'm not sure about your usecase here, but why not just import the clsification engine and executes it inside that if block?

Comment: Check [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62796798/6262757) :)