# Watchdog ignore pattern

Tags: python, python-3.x, watchdog, python-watchdog

I tried working with other posts on here about this, but couldn't get it to work. I'm a newbie with Python.

I need help with `ignore_pattern`.

I'm uploading images to a folder and temporarily images are being added with `__`, so the actual image added while file is uploading is `__image-name.jpg`. After it's done uploading it gets added again as `image-name.jpg` (and deletes the `__image-name.jpg`.

I want to ignore all the `__image-name.jpg` files with watchdog.

Here's my code:

```
class Watcher:
    DIRECTORY_TO_WATCH = "director/where/images/are/uploaded"

    def __init__(self):
        self.observer = Observer()

    def run(self):
        event_handler = Handler()
        self.observer.schedule(event_handler, self.DIRECTORY_TO_WATCH, recursive=True)
        self.observer.start()
        try:
            while True:
                time.sleep(5)
        except:
            self.observer.stop()
            print("Error")

        self.observer.join()


class Handler(FileSystemEventHandler):

    @staticmethod
    def on_any_event(event):
        if event.is_directory:
            return None

        elif event.event_type == 'created':
            # Take any action here when a file is first created.
            print(event.src_path)
            img = Image.open(event.src_path)
            for result in engine.classify_with_image(img, top_k=3):
              print('---------------------------')
              print(labels[result[0]])
              print('Score : ', result[1])

        # elif event.event_type == 'modified':
            # Taken any action here when a file is modified.
            # print("Received modified event - %s." % event.src_path)

        elif event.event_type == 'deleted':
            # Taken any action here when a file is deleted.
            print("Received deleted event - %s." % event.src_path)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    w = Watcher()
    w.run()
```

Thank you so much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does `event.src_path` returns a string? If so you can use the `startswith` method of the string class to skip over the images you don't want.
For example:

```
elif event.event_type == 'created':
            # Take any action here when a file is first created.
            print(event.src_path)
            
            # Check if this filename starts with "__" and execute the next block
            if not event.src_path.startswith('__'):
              img = Image.open(event.src_path)
              for result in engine.classify_with_image(img, top_k=3):
                print('---------------------------')
                print(labels[result[0]])
                print('Score : ', result[1])
            # else do nothing
```

Comment: Thank you! it returns the full path of the image:
home/pi/Media/plant-classification/1200px-Sunflower_sky_backdrop.jpg

Something with `.contains` instead, maybe?

Comment: Got it working with this `if "__" not in event.src_path:` Thank you so much for all the help. I'm pretty new with Python and using the Coral Accelerator. Still trying to figure things out.

Comment: no problem, an up vote on answer would be supper :)